# How to add custom textbox field on shopify product page that also shown in cart under product description

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, shopify

I need to add custom textbox field on shopify product pages.

My requirement is to add textbox field on product page and when customer add product in cart than that textbox field value also display on cart page and also on checkout page.

```
<p class="line-item-property__field">   <label for="custom-field">Your custom field</label>   <input id="custom-field" type="text" name="properties[Your custom field]"> </p>
```